# ms excel find and replace @ symbol results in broken formula

Tags: microsoft-excel, find-and-replace

I'm trying to search and replace in excel, the column is formatted as 'Text'.

Find: [@

replace with: @

Whenever this finds a match at the start of a cell i.e the cell contents start with [@
and tries to replace that with @ the result is an error 'This function is not valid'

I guess that since the @ operator is for references, this is causing the cell to be interpreted differently (not as text anymore)

How do I make this replacement work?

Copy/paste into another program is not a good option because some of the cells contain line-breaks.

Comment: Is replacing with `'@` acceptable? The `'` symbol will not be visible.

Comment: I tried that, but the apostrophe appears when you copy/paste into another text editor, I need the output to be clean, because it's being used by another program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To my surprise, Excel knows at least 4 different methods to replace a substring.

All of them can handle a leading `@` in the way you want it. Except the first method which you are using when opening the *search & replace* dialog.

The `@` is the [text placeholder.](http://www.databison.com/custom-format-in-excel-how-to-format-numbers-and-text/). If you enter a numeric value like `123` in a cell and set the custom format to `@`, the cell will be formatted as text (Alignment: right » left).

---

These examples will all replace the `b` in cell A1' value `abc` with `123`. Result is always `a123c`.

**1. Range.Replace()** (same as <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd> dialog)

```
    [A1].Replace "b", "123", xlPart
```

[Syntax:](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff194086.aspx) `Range.Replace( What, Replacement, [LookAt], [SearchOrder], [MatchCase], [SearchFormat], [ReplaceFormat] )`

**2. WorksheetFunction.Replace()**

```
    [A1] = WorksheetFunction.Replace([A1], InStr([A1], "b"), Len("b"), "123")
```

[Syntax:](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace.php) `WorksheetFunction.Replace( old_text, start, number_of_chars, new_text )`

**3. WorksheetFunction.Substitute()**

```
    [A1] = WorksheetFunction.Substitute([A1], "b", "123")
```

[Syntax:](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/substitute.php) `WorksheetFunction.Substitute( text, old_text, new_text, [nth_appearance] )`

**4. Replace()**

```
    [A1] = Replace([A1], "b", "123")
```

[Syntax:](http://www.techonthenet.com/excel/formulas/replace_vba.php) `Replace( Expression, Find, Replace, [Start, [Count, [Compare]]] )`

---

To answer Loopo's question. You should use the last method since it can handle `@` at the beginning of a cell value. I made it a little bit more comfortable with 2 input boxes.

```
Sub ReplaceFunction()
    strFind = InputBox("Find what")
    strReplace = InputBox("Replace with")

    For Each cell In Selection
        cell.Value = Replace(cell.Value, strFind, strReplace)
    Next
End Sub
```

[image]